# In Arch linux, is there any way to update one particular package?

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade, rolling-release

In Arch linux, is there any way to update one particular package? Without uninstalling it.

Comment: [Partial upgrades are unsupported](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported)... Whatever you are actually trying to do, this is the wrong way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *jasonwryan* notes this is not generally a wise approach, but simply `pacman -S <pkg name>` will install the latest version and anything that it depends on, though I'm not sure what your meaning:

> Without uninstalling it

Are you attempting to keep multiple versions of the same package? if so, then no I do not think archlinux will support this ootb. I think you'd need to look into containerization to accomplish something like this.

Comment: Well, technically, `-S $pkg` will install the package version that matches the local db, which means if it is already installed it will report it as such, and if it isn't it will 404 when pacman tries to retrieve it if there is a newer version.

Comment: Ah sure this does assume a synchronized database, otherwise it would be `pacman -Sy $pkg` to first synchronize and install said package.

Comment: Yes, but [never -Sy $pkg](http://gist.io/5660494)...

Comment: Agreed. It is possible, but never should be done as evidenced by the above cautionary tale.

Comment: @jasonwryan, I will.